# Different behaviour between new tls.TLSSocket() followed by connect(..) versus tls.connect(..)

Tags: node.js, sockets, tls1.2

I'm attempting to use the following code to create a TLS Socket in nodejs

```
const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
let tlsSocket = new tls.TLSSocket()

socket.on('connect', (connectionData) => {
  // Do extra work with socket
  tlsSocket.connect({
    host: targetHost,
    port: targetPort,
    socket: socket,
  })
}
```

and this is causing an ECONNREFUSED error. The events I see in this flow on tlsSocket are

- lookup
- error ECONNREFUSED
- _tlsError
- close

But if I change the code to

```
const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.setEncoding('utf8');

socket.on('connect', (connectionData) => {
  // Do extra work with socket
  let tlsSocket = tls.connect({
    host: targetHost,
    port: targetPort,
    socket: socket,
  })
}
```

It works with events on the tlsSocket

- resume
- data
- readable
- end
- prefinish
- finish
- close

Why does this fail if I create the constructor version of the TLSSocket and `connect` it later. Rather than when I use `tls.connect(..)` which passes.

I need a reference to the tls socket to be returned before the socket `connect` event. Hence this is blocking me.